SONY XPERIA 10 II does not find contacts in contact list
Mobile OS ANDROID 12, I have over 1000 contacts, synced also in Google Account, but mobile finds only few contacts with similar name beginning: for example "TOOMAS" found 4 persons, on list over 20 "Toomas ... ".

What happens if you do the same search on https://contacts.google.com - do you get the same result or do you get all contacts as expected?
